# Override actions defined in parent class Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I am upgrading a Django project from Django 1.11. I have successfully upgraded the project upto Django 2.1. When I upgraded to Django 2.2, I got this error message
"(admin.E130) **name** attributes of actions defined in class AdimClass(not real name) must be unique"

The admins classes are

```py
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

    def custom_action(self, request, queryset):
        # perform  custom action
        .....

    def custom_action_2(self, request, queryset):
        # another custom actions
        .....


    action = [custom_action, custom_action_2]


class BAdmin(AAdmin):

    def custom_action(self, request, queryset):
        # performs different actions but has the same name as AAdmin action
        .....
    actions = AAdmin.actions + [custom_action]
```

**problem:** (admin.E130) **name** attributes of actions defined in class AdimClass(not real name) must be unique

If I remove the custom_action from **AAdmin**, the error is resolved but the action is no more available for other classes which inherits **AAdmin**.

**Goal:** keep the action in parent class **AAdmin** and override it on child class **BAdmin**.

**Note:** The code is working fine upto Django 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to add the same action name "custom_action" to BAdmin twice, the first is inherited by AAdmin. The solution is to not include the duplicate action. A possible solution:

```
class BAdmin(AAdmin):

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = AAdmin.actions
      
        if 'custom_action' in actions:
            del actions['custom_action']
    
        return actions + [custom_action]
```